# Using arrays with the Calendar class in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, calendar

I'm trying to create a rather complex array for my calendar application. It's supposed to contain dates, with the name of the day, the 'type' and the events, if any. I got as far as creating this:

```
[dates] {
        [22] {
             [day] => [Friday]
             [type] => [weekday]                              
        }
        [23] {
             [day] => [Saturday]
             [type] => [Weekend]
        }
        [24] {
             [day] => [Sunday]
             [type] => [Weekend]
        }
}
```

Now I would like to add another key called 'events'. I want to add the events for each day to the array.. So I could get something like:

```
        [24] {
             [day] => [Sunday]
             [type] => [Weekend]
             [events] {
                      [1] {
                          [title] => [test event]
                          [description] => [my event]
                          [date] => [24-04-2011]
                      }
                      [2] {
                          [title] => [test event 2]
                          [description] => [my second event]
                          [date] => [24-04-2011]
                      }
              }
```

Not sure if this makes sense.

I created the first example using this code:

```
        for($i = 1; $i <= $data['days_in_curr_month']; $i++)
    {
        $day_info = $this->get_day_info($i, $data['current_month'], $data['current_year']);

        $dates[$i]['name'] = $day_info['day_name'];
        $dates[$i]['type'] = $day_info['day_type'];
    }

    return $dates;
```

I then wanted to grab the event info by doing:

`$event_info = $this->get_event_info($i, $data['current_month'], $data['current_year']);`

in the same for loop.

My get_event_info method looks like this:

```
    public function get_event_info($day, $month, $year)
{
    $date = $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day;
    $this->db->where('date', $date);
    $this->db->where('user_id', '1');   
    $query = $this->db->get('tblEvents');

    $event_info = array();

    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $event_info['events'][$row->id]['title'] = $row->title;
        $event_info['events'][$row->id]['description'] = $row->description;
    }

    return $event_info;

}
```

It outputs arrays like this:

```
Array ( [events] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [title] => Project 2 [description] => Test: Project 2 ) [2] => Array ( [title] => Illustrator [description] => Test: Illustrator 2 ) ) )
```

Now, I return the $event_info from `get_events_info` to the `create_dates_list` method, but I'm not sure how I would go about adding my event arrays to the $dates array.

The get_event_info gets the events for each date (1 - end of month-). I then want to add those to my $dates array in the format listed above in my second example.

I'm confused cause these are rather complex arrays. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need to do is (for example):

```
 $append_events = get_event_info($day, $month, $year);
 $array['dates']['1']['event'] = $append_events['events'];
```

Then you can access your elements:

```
 $array['dates']['1']['event'][$id]['title']    
 $array['dates']['1']['event'][$id]['description']
```

Comment: Thanks; that did it. Wasn't so hard after all, I was trying too hard, I guess. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @cabaret I work with complex arrays all day long at work.  A few more months with PHP and you will be too!