# CodeIgniter $this->load->vars()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm wondering how `$this->load->vars()` works in CodeIgniter. The documentation is fairly vague about it.

I have the following code:

```
    $init = $this->init->set();

    $this->load->view('include/header', $init);
    $this->load->view('include/nav');

    $dates = $this->planner_model->create_date_list();
    $this->load->view('planner/dates_content', $dates);

    $detail = $this->planner_model->create_detail_list();
    $this->load->view('planner/detail_content', $detail);


    $this->load->view('include/footer');
```

However, I also need the `$dates`array in my `detail_content` view. I was trying to load it with `$this->load->vars()` and hoping it would append to the `$detail` array, because the CI documentation states as follows:

> You can have multiple calls to this function. The data get cached and merged into one array for conversion to variables.

Would it work if I do `$detail['dates'] = $dates;` ? Will it append the `$dates` array to `$detail['dates']` then?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$this->load->vars()` is perfect for this purpose. Try this:

```
$init = $this->init->set();// Won't be passed to the next 2 views
$this->load->view('include/header', $init);
$this->load->view('include/nav');

$dates = $this->planner_model->create_date_list();
$this->load->vars($dates);
$this->load->view('planner/dates_content');

$detail = $this->planner_model->create_detail_list();
$this->load->vars($detail);
$this->load->view('planner/detail_content');
```

What looks strange to me is that normally you pass an associative array as data, like `$data['my_var_name'] = $var_value`, so I assume your model calls are returning the data already structured with the variable names (array keys) that you'll use in your view which I do find odd, but then I know nothing of your application.

Here's a more "conventional" version:

```
$data['dates'] = $this->planner_model->create_date_list();
$this->load->view('planner/dates_content', $data);

$data['detail'] = $this->planner_model->create_detail_list();
// receives both dates and detail
$this->load->view('planner/detail_content', $data);
```

Comment: But, with your code, will I have access to the $dates array in my detail_content view? Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Yes you will have access to those variables.

Comment: My data is indeed already structured when it returns from my model. May I ask why is this odd? Is it 'bad' per se? Thanks.

Comment: I find it odd because Model should not be talking directly to View. The return value of the Model call should be as "raw" as possible to make it reusable, not returning arbitrary key/value pairs for use in the view... Like I said, I have no idea how much sense it makes in your situation, it might be a great idea, but it is certainly unconventional.

Comment: If you have time to look at it, this is what my array looks like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764998/using-arrays-with-the-calendar-class-in-codeigniter Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I'll edit my code to reflect the conventional way.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just just building an array that you pass to the different views? I find `$this->load->vars()` behaves unexpectedly.

Comment: Was just updating my post with an idea when you posted this. :)

Comment: YBuild an array like `$viewdata['dates']`. Then load your view with `$this->load->view('header', $viewdata)`. Then you can use `echo $dates` in your view. You can pass the same array to each view.

Answer (score 2):

As is stated in other answers, and in the user guide, using `$this->load->vars()` is the same as including the second argument in `$this->load->view()`.

But from the user guide:

> The reason you might want to use this function independently is if you would like to set some global variables in the constructor of your controller and have them become available in any view file loaded from any function.

This to me, is the only reason you'd use `$this->load->vars()`.  As @madmartigan says, it's more convenient to use the view loader with the second argument.